# How to solve system of equations without using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am completely stuck with this system of equation. It should be easy, but it's not.

$\frac{15-V_2}{20}+\frac{V_3-V_2}{30}-\frac{V_2}{15}=0$

$\frac{V_2-V_3}{30}-\frac{V_3}{15}=0$

I need some guidance with this one. All my solutions have become really small, like 0.000000006 small, and I know that the correct solution is $V_3=1.8$

Comment: why do you not simplify $0-V_2=-V_2$?

Comment: and $0-V_3=-V_3$?

Comment: Because I still do not know how to move forward, and that simplification does not make any easier to calculate

Answer (score -1):

multiplying your second equation by $30$ we get
$$V_2-V_3-2V_3=0$$ this means $$V_2=3V_3$$
plugging this in your first equation you will obtain
$$\frac{15-3V_3}{20}+\frac{V_3-3V_3}{30}-\frac{3V_3}{15}=0$$
can you finish?
multiplying your last equation by $60$ you will get
$$45-9V_3+2V_3-6V_3-12V_3=0$$ and now?

Comment: Yes I think so. My brain was somewhere far away, but I think I found it now. Thank You

Comment: ok we can compare the results later, good luck!

Comment: Okay, solving your way got me 1.8 as it should, but when I tried a method my own I got 3.75 but I will get some food and sleep and try again tomorrow. I will not give up on this one!

Comment: ok Keep solving!

Comment: have a good food